# Angular: How to access parent and child of JSON for showing breadcrumb

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to make some thing like that, if any subchild have any array like 'Group' then show the all parent in breadcrumbs. I am new in angular. I could not build the logic how can I do this. For this I can not provide the code.

JSON:

```js
[{
    "ID": "01",
    "Name": "Level 1",
    "parentId": null,
    "sublevel": [{
      "ID": "01-01",
      "Name": "Level 1-1",
      "parentId": "01",
      "sublevel": [{
        "ID": "01-01-01",
        "Name": "Level 1-1-1",
        "parentId": "01-01",
        "sublevel": [],
        "Groups": [{
          "GroupID": "1",
          "GroupName": "group 1",
          "assigned": true
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "ID": "02",
    "Name": "Level 2",
    "parentId": null,
    "sublevel": [{
      "ID": "02-01",
      "Name": "Level 2-1",
      "parentId": "02",
      "sublevel": [],
      "Groups": [{
        "GroupID": "2",
        "GroupName": "group 2",
        "assigned": true
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "ID": "03",
    "Name": "Level 3",
    "parentId": null,
    "sublevel": []
  }
]
```

Want to make Something Like That:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a recursive component, which should use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` structural directives in your html, let's say this json will be named as `menuItems: Array<any>`

```
<div *ngIf="menu">
<span *ngFor="let item of menu">
  <span *ngIf="!isDeepestStep(item)">
    {{  
        isRoot 
        ? item.Name 
        : ' > '  + item.Name 
    }}
    <span *ngFor="let subItem of item.sublevel">
        <span *ngIf="isDeepestStep(subItem)">
          {{ ' > ' + subItem.Name }}
          <span *ngFor="let group of subItem.Groups">
            [boxed] {{ group.GroupName }}
          </span>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="!isDeepestStep(subItem)">
          {{ ' > ' + subItem.Name }} 
          <menu [isRoot]="false" [menu]="subItem.sublevel"></menu>
        </span>
    </span> 
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="isDeepestStep(item)">
    {{ item.Name }}
    <span *ngFor="let group of item.Groups">
      [boxed] {{ group.GroupName }}
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

you should have a method which will tell if that's a lowest step which has data in your component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent  {
  @Input() menu: Array<any>;
  @Input() isRoot: boolean;

  isDeepestStep(item: any): boolean {
    return !(item.sublevel && item.sublevel.length > 0);
  }
}
```

working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gy8dv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu.component.ts)

PS. I am sure it can be even more simplified, but in hurry I came up with such solution

Comment: I want to show the lists which has Group Array. For example Level-3 have no group, so it will not shown

Comment: @YJunction updated my answer, I didn't see a screenshot at first. This solution is not the best, and as I mentioned it can be simplified and optimized

Comment: It works good. It helps me a lot. If you find any better solution, I hope you will post it.